# Matlab and sorting single results to a matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting

```
for i=1:1:k   %k = 100 people
   for j=1:1:l  %l = 5 orders
      Resultx = a + b + d(j); % cost of drink Resultx
      Resulty = f + g + c(j); % cost of food Resulty
   end
   Matrix(i) = [Resultsx1...j Resulty1...j]
end
```

Those `% notes` are for helping me express the problem I want to solve in my mind, and later on, in my script.

Lets claim that we want for each `i` to store values in a matrix of costs of the drinks and food it orders.

So for people `i = 1`,

```
1[1 5] %people 1, first order:  drink costs 1 and food costs 5
2[2 3] %people 1, second order: drink costs 2 and food costs 3
      ...
j[x y] %people 1, j order:      drink and food costs x and y
                 !!!       Matrix(1) = sort (j [x,y])    !!!
```

for people `i = 2`,

```
1[1 5] %people 2, first order:  drink costs 1 and food costs 5
2[2 3] %people 2, second order: drink costs 2 and food costs 3
     ...
j[x y] %people 2, j order:      drink and food costs x and y
       !!!       Matrix(2) = sort (j [x,y])    !!!
```

for people `i = k`,

```
1[1 5] %people k, first order:  drink costs 1 and food costs 5
2[2 3] %people k, second order: drink costs 2 and food costs 3
      ...
j[x y] %people k, j order:      drink and food costs x and y
            !!!       Matrix(i) = sort (j [x,y])    !!!
```

I want to form every result of each `i`<sup>th</sup> iteration to a Matrix in ascending order

```
Matrix(i) = sort (j [x,y]).
```

Perhaps not the best paradigm, but thank you in advance.

Comment: Your wording is a little vague: 1) the definition of `sort(j [x, y])` is not clear. 2) Is `Matrix(i)` a scalar or an entire row? Can you provide a valid mathematical formula for it? 3) You're using `k` both as a number (in the external `for` loop) and as a function/vector (in the computation of `Resultx`). Which is correct?

Comment: Do you put price of food and price of drinks in the same array and mix them (and then you want to sort that array) or do you want for those two values to be ordered pair (and then want to sort that array of ordered pairs). If you want the latter you should precisely define comparator according to which you want to sort...

Comment: @EitanT: 1. I wanna sort each i results in ascending order of the (Resultx and Resulty) of j, for every i, sort(Resultx(j),Resulty(j)). 2. Can not my mind is ready to blow atm, sorry. 3. fixed.

Comment: @zplesivcak: I want every array of the Matrix to contain pairs of (Resultx(j),Resulty(j)) and then this matrix to be sorted in pairs so i can choose the min or the max of the matrix, according to sorting, by index parsing of the sorted pairs/elements.

Comment: @EitanT: If that helps more: Matrix(i) = [Resultx(j) Resulty(j) : Resultx(j+1) Resulty(j+1) : ... : Resultx(l) Resulty(l)]; sort(Matrix(i,j));

Comment: From your explanation I infer that `Matrix(i, j)` is the element in the (i, j) location of `Matrix`, so it's meaningless to write `sort(Matrix(i, j))`. Please explain what you are sorting. Are you sorting the rows or the columns of Matrix?

Comment: From your explanation I infer that `Matrix(i, j` is the element in the (i, j) location of Matrix, so it's meaningless to write `sort(Matrix(i, j))`. Please explain what you are sorting. Rows? Columns?

Comment: @EitanT: The Matrix(i,j) should have dimensions of k * l. Each row i consisted from j elements(pairs). Those j pairs elements (Resultx Resulty) can not be sorted for each i? So according to my paradigm: For each people i find and sort in ascending the order j which cost the most money to less (without adding Resultsx,y together). Something Close to this perhaps Matrix(people) = sort(Resultx(order) Resulty(order)).

Comment: I just can't resist: "i wanna" is how you say it in the streets of most US cities; it's not actually English. Please make a habit of *writing* "I want to" ("I" is **ALWAYS** capitalized, and "wanna" is a contraction of "want to" used in *spoken* language only). I won't go into discussing the importance of correct punctuation here...:)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Thanks for the better representation of my question. All the times i use the "I want to" and i have never been in US cities. I use it once in a rush and attract spelling correction, no offense given or taken. I focus on my question and trying to solve it.

Comment: Hm, you're `Resultx` and `Resulty` doesn't in any way depend on `i`? That way will values for all the people be the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Two ways I understood your statement; I'm presuming you're interested in **2.** solution. In this form `Resultx` and `Resulty` don't depend on `i` in any way, and therefore they'll be the same for all the "people").*

**1.** `Matrix` is *[ k* **x** *2 ]* array. Results from second loop are *summed up!*

```
Matrix = zeros(k, 2);                 % pre-allocate space

for i=1:1:k   %k = 100 people
    Resultx = 0;
    Resulty = 0;        
    for j=1:1:l  %l = 5 orders
        Resultx = Resultx + a + b + d(j);       % cost of drink Resultx
        Resulty = Resulty + f + g + c(j);       % cost of food Resulty
    end
    Matrix(i,:) = [Resultx, Resulty]  % save pair
end

Sorted = sortrows(Matrix, [1 2]);     % sort pairs
```

Last command [sorts pairs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ordinal.sortrows.html), first by 1st column, then by 2nd column in *ascending* order. If you would like *descending* order for both criteria, you would use `[-1 -2]` instead. Combining ascending and descending is also possible (for example `[-1 2]`) but senselessness is questionable in this case.

**2.** `Matrix` is *[ k* **x** *l* **x** *2 ]* array in which the results are *kept individually and are not summed up* in second loop.

```
Matrix = zeros(k, l, 2);              % pre-allocate space
Intermediate = zeros(l, 2);           % container used for sorting

for i=1:1:k   %k = 100 people
    for j=1:1:l  %l = 5 orders
        Resultx = a + b + d(j);       % cost of drink Resultx
        Resulty = f + g + c(j);       % cost of food Resulty
        Intermediate(j,:) = [Resultx, Resulty];  %save pair
    end
    Matrix(i,:,:) = sortrows(Intermediate, [1 2]);  % sort pairs
end
```

---

**Note:** *You should do avoid writing loops in Matlab and resort to vectorized solution wherever possible!*

Comment: @zplesivcak: For 2nd solution, which is suitable to my occasion, 'Sorted = sortrows(Matrix, [1 2]);' returns error:  Error using sortrows, X must be a 2-D matrix. Also on 'Matrix(i,:,:) = sortrows(Intermediate, [1 2]);' if you change [1 2]  to [1 -2] sort does not change. I am trying to investigate this and i ll report back.

Comment: @professor I'm sorry, that was a relic; fixed now. Second criteria (`2` or `-2` in your case; for second column) is used only if pairs are equal comparing by first criteria (1st column) - [see reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ordinal.sortrows.html)!